# Начальная страница в зависимости от роли пользователя

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2

Как определить начальную страницу в зависимости от роли пользователя?

Что бы с одними ролями

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Agent, SuperVizer")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

шли сюда, а с другими

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Ispolnitel")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexIspolnitel()
```

сюда.

Как я понимаю, роутинг определен в Startup.cs но как изменить его что бы он учитывал роль.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал, так не уверен что совсем правильно но работает.

```
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Ispolnitel"))
            {
                return Redirect("/Home/IndexIspolnitel");
            }


            if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("AGENT") || HttpContext.User.IsInRole("SuperVizer"))
            {
                return Redirect("/Home/IndexAgent");
            }                
            return View();
        }
```